# Observable for RxWorker in android workmanager

Tags: android, observable, android-workmanager

I am using `WorkManager` and `RxWorker` for observing battery status changes from  system. Facing problem when using Observable and converting it to `Single<result>` as `RxWorker` support only `Single<result>`. Here is my code snippet.

```
override fun createWork(): Single<Result> {
    return Single.fromObservable(ReactiveBattery.observeBatteryChanges(appContext)
            .map { batteryState ->
                try {
                    Timber.e("Test with batterystate %s", batteryState.toString())
                    outputData = workDataOf(BATTERY_LEVEL to batteryState.level())
                    Result.success(outputData)
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    Timber.e(e, "Test ")
                    Result.failure()
                }

            })
}
```

Here is my `observeBatteryChanges()` code.

```
@CheckResult
  @NonNull
  public static Observable<BatteryState> observeBatteryChanges(@NonNull final Context context) {
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(context, "context == null");
    BatteryObservingStrategy strategy = new GenericBatteryObservingStrategy();

    return strategy.observeBatteryChanges(context);
  }
```

Its running but with `FAILED` status, I am not getting the `SUCCEEDED` status and also observable not triggering of OS battery changes.

Can anybody suggest how i can do this?

Comment: Why are you using WorkManager to monitor battery changes? What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I have already an library which return BatteryState Observable. Which updates the battery status based on OS events. I need to monitor the battery status to update different UI of my application. That's why using RxWorker to pass those status data into viewmodel.

Comment: It's not clear to me why you need WorkManager in between your library and the viewmodel. Can you observe the BatteryState observable in the ViewModel itself?

Comment: Yup, I can but its data source and viewmodel should not responsible for data source. It should be in data layer. However, my question is how can i observe data changes of observable using work manager.

Comment: WorkManager is intended for background/foreground task, this involves some limits on how long you can run them: e.g. there is a hard limit of 10minutes, after that your work is stopped. I don't think that a `RxWorker` (or WorkManager in general) is the right choice here.